# Como guardar datos de solo lectura en android?

Tags: java, android

estoy desarrollando una app Android que realiza aprox unas 100 preguntas(un test) y quisiera saber cual es la manera mas recomendada de guardar el titulo de la pregunta, las opciones y la respuesta correcta para acceder a estos datos desde la Actividad, osea que no se si guardarlos en un xml, en un archivo sql, en un array de string statico y final desde java, en un array en strings.xml, etc. Aunque creo que cualquiera de estos me serviria para lo mismo no se cual es el mejor en cuanto a rendimiento para acceder a los datos mas rapido...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera correcta en la que deberias hacer esto es utilizando SQLite pero no es algo que te pueda responder aqui con ejemplos ya que es un tema relativamente extenso mas no muy complicado si ya tienes bases en SQL.

Te dejo esta liga, yo personalmente de aqui lo aprendi:
http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-sqlite-bases-de-datos/

Es un tutorial muy completo, que no te de flojera, ánimo!, SQLite es algo muy utilizado en android, asi que si vas a comenzar a desarrollar apps que requieran guardar informacion en la memoria del telefono la mejor practica es hacerlo con SQLite.

Tambien esta la opcion de los servicios web, crearlos, levantarlos y consumirlos desde tu app, pero requieres ese conocimiento tecnico y un requerimiento es tener conexion a internet en tu tel.

Saludos!